Small sprites in Unity look pixelated, and need anti-aliasing
I've got a sprite in-game (using a Sprite Renderer) that was drawn by our artist at a very high resolution, but in-game can appear quite small on-screen:

My boss has been complaining that the character looks very "pixelated" (his words) in-game. I'm noticing that when comparing it to e.g. the Windows Photos viewer, there's a lot of jaggedness. I think this was called antialiasing? I've tried ticking the option to generate mipmaps in the inspector for the texture, but it still doesn't quite look smooth compared to Windows Photos viewer at the same size on my screen:

What possible solutions can I try? Note that the camera does zoom in at points, so I can't just downscale his sprite outside of Unity. I'm about to try switching render pipelines so that I can enable antialiasing. I'm on Unity 2020.3.25f1.
Import&Display settings below:



What are your import and display settings for that sprite?

@Zibelas I've added the import settings, but I'm unsure what display settings refer to. I've added the Sprite Renderer but otherwise in my Graphics settings I have no Render Pipeline Asset assigned, yet (was going to try that next).

And how big is your original image? You can as well try to set Filter Mode to ‘Point‘ and or the Compression to ‘None‘. If your image is as well bigger than 2048, you need to adjust that one too. Last thing you can as well try to change the Mesh Type.

The original image is very large, around 5000x3000 pixels. I've used the Max Size options in import to scale it down to 2048. The rest of your comment sounds like an answer -- you should submit it as one.

5000x3000 sounds really big for an image in the first place that will be rendered later at around 200x100 if I eyeball your screen. Depending how your camera zooms you might be better of with having two images (a big image can be quite memory hungry).

I have "Max Size: 2048" in my import settings.

You might be interested in this past Q&A: Sprite becomes blurry or jagged when camera zooms out. In particular, I'd recommend changing "Compression" to "RGBA 32-bit", as vector art sprites generally do not look good with GPU texture compression. It's also a good idea to avoid non-power-of-two scaling. If you know you'll never use this image larger than 2048, save the asset at 2048, rather than scaling it down by a non-power-of-two amount on import. That limits the maximum quality any future steps can attain by giving them a distorted input.

I don't think it's fair to compare an image on a "black" background with one that isn't. There's a whole science to contrasting colors. And a "moving" image always has to think about pixel alignment; a static one doesn't. I use a radial brush into transparent if I don't like the way a particular "hard" edge  looks. (The characters' shadows are rather feeble ... that makes them more "ghostly" (IMO)).

On of the problems is the unantialiased lines on the creases character's shirt and sleeves, which are on the same background of the character's shirt and sleeves.

Set filter to point, disable compression, and don't generate mipmaps (or ensure they aren't being used).  This should help.  Also, the original image should be sized in a power of 2, ideally, to help avoid resizing causing "pixelation".  AA is helpful, but relying on it to fix asset issues isn't ideal.
